# get_post_gallery with Gutenberg

Tags: images, gallery, block-editor

I have a site where I created a page that takes the gallery images from a post and puts them into a slider.

I used the following code:

```
// gets the gallery info
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post->ID, false );
// makes an array of image ids
$ids = explode ( ",", $gallery['ids'] );
```

Then I inserted the images using wp_get_attachment_image().

Unfortunately, with WP 5.0 and Gutenberg, get_post_gallery no longer works with newly added content. It seems that get_post_gallery used a shortcode that no longer works with Gutenberg.

I am still getting up to speed on Gutenberg and the block system. Until I understand that all better, I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how to get the image ids from a gallery in Gutenberg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using birgire's suggestions, I came up with the following solution that is working well with both the old pre-WP 4.x data and the newer posts that have been added under 5.0.

```
// if there is a gallery block do this
if (has_block('gallery', $post->post_content)) {
    $post_blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);
    $ids = $post_blocks[0][attrs][ids];
} 
// if there is not a gallery block do this
else {
    // gets the gallery info
    $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post->ID, false );
    // makes an array of image ids
    $ids = explode ( ",", $gallery['ids'] );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `get_post_gallery()` is a wrapper for `get_post_galleries()` that has an open ticket 
[#43826](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43826) for gallery blocks support. This is currently set to the 5.1 milestone, but it might change.

You can even look at the proposed [patches](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/43826/43826.6.diff), that uses e.g. `parse_blocks( $post->post_content )` and `has_block( 'gallery', $post->post_content )` , to get an idea what's needed to fully support this.

In the meanwhile you could look into the `render_block` filter to modify the rendered output of gallery blocks to your needs.

Here's an example that targets the `core/gallery` block and uses the block attribute containing the gallery image IDs:

```
/**
 * Modify the output of the rendered core/gallery block.
 */
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'core/gallery' !== $block['blockName'] || ! isset( $block['attrs']['ids'] ) ) {
           return $block_content;
    }
    $li = '';
    foreach( (array) $block['attrs']['ids'] as $id ) {
        $li .= sprintf( '<li>%s</li>', wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'large' ) );
    }
    return sprintf( '<ul>%s</ul>', $li ); 
}, 10, 2 );
```