# How to get all gallery blocks in wp_query like get_post_gallery()?

Tags: block-editor

before Gutenberg I could query for all galleries in my blog with this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
      echo get_post_gallery();
endwhile;
```

But this does not output Gutenberg galleries. How do I output Gutenberg block galleries?

Comment: This is an open feature request in wp Core: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43826

Comment: Relates to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325428/get-post-gallery-with-gutenberg